# html/php multiple select with two values

Tags: php, mysql

I currently edit an open source program and have a question: the php code is actually like this:

```
print "<select multiple name=\"appliesto[]\" size=\"5\">";
foreach ($products as $k => $v) {
    $pid = $k;
    $group = $v['group'];
    $prodname = $v['name'];
    print "<option value=\"$pid\">$group - $prodname</option>";
}
print "</select>
```

Is it possible to get 2 values with each selected option? Because I need to save $pid and $prodname in 2 different columns on a mysql table.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not possible. Can't you just look up the product name in the database since you have the product id?

Comment: I was just about to say what @joserojas said, however you could also have a json string as the value, then on the other end you just decode it and you then already have an array.

Answer (score 3):

You can put at the value attribute some delimiter to the values something like this:

```
print "<select multiple name=\"appliesto[]\" size=\"5\">";
foreach ($products as $k => $v) {
    $pid = $k;
    $group = $v['group'];
    $prodname = $v['name'];
    print "<option value=\"$pid|$prodname\">$group - $prodname</option>";
}
print "</select>
```

when you post the data you can explode the data by the delimiter in this case `|` in order to get the 2 values.

```
list($pid,$prodname) = explode("|", $inputSelect, 2);
```

Comment: If you use this solution, make sure there is no `|` character in the product name.

Comment: Also, might I suggest `list($pid,$prodname) = explode("|", $inputSelect, 2);`? Just to make it shorter and the extra limit parameter in the explode function call ensures that only two elements are returned (in case there is a pipe character in the product name).